# How to use Android voice recognition to recognise a phrase

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm writing an android app and I want to use the android OS voice recognition. How do I incorporate it into the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the API Demo, "VoiceRecognition" - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

That should give you a head start.